# Signalr hosting client scripts for javascript client in server

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

I have SingnalR (OWIN self-hosted) server hub working with .net client. Now i'm preparing to write web client. I see that hub scripts are served http://localhost:10102/signalr/hubs but cannot see Scripts/jquery-*.min.js and Scripts/jquery.signalR-*.min.js.

I assume those scripts are not served from server hub (but by default included by nuget to solution) - am i right or missing something? 
Is there a way to reference those scripts directly form server (not to copy and host them on javascript client side)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client:

> A JavaScript client requires references to jQuery and the SignalR core
>   JavaScript file. The jQuery version must be 1.6.4 or major later
>   versions, such as 1.7.2, 1.8.2, or 1.9.1. If you decide to use the
>   generated proxy, you also need a reference to the SignalR generated
>   proxy JavaScript file. The following example shows what the references
>   might look like in an HTML page that uses the generated proxy.

You have only to add the following scripts to your index.html (take care about the versions):

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

**Serve these files from server:**

1. Create directory in server project where you place these JS Files
2. Configure your server that he serves theses files. For that add `app.UseFileServer();` to you `Configure(...)` method in Startup class. (See details about service files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files)
3. Add the required scripts in client. There is an example (change adresses and script file to your files and you server adress:

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:10310/scripts/signalr-clientES5-1.0.0-alpha2-final.js></script>`

Comment: Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js is part of client side. Can it be served from signalr server host?

Comment: @ITMan: I edited my anwer. This solutions works. I tested it for short.

Comment: Got it work with inspiration of your answer. Thanks for your help! I'm not sure how to mark the answer inside this thread...?

Comment: @IT Man. Check mark on left side? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Comment: :) well i know how to mark the answer. I was not sure if your answer i exact one - for sure it was right clue!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to have scripts to implement SygnalR service (backend part). To make a connection between client index.html and your service, you need to have some kind of client lib that works with SygnalR to establish a connection.

Comment: I know i can include those scripts from anywhere but i would rather like to serve them from signalr server host. That would ensure version compatibility for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the EXACT solution I came into, based on answers inside this thread:

Static files (like additional javascript files) can be served within same host with configuration of below. Scripts will be available at http://{yourhost}/scripts/{scriptName} when placed inside \Scripts folder iniside solution ('copy if newer' has to be set for 'Copy To Output Directory' for each of the files).

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
                // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
                // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
                // providing a cors options with a different policy.
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                    // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                    // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                    // EnableJSONP = true
                };
                // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
                // path.
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });

            // Serving javascript libraries required for client as static content from Scripts folder
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() {
                RequestPath = new PathString("/scripts"),
                FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@".\Scripts"),
            });
        }
    }
```

IT Man